# How to login using 'ion auth'?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

Regarding 'ion auth', there is an error when I try to login. My `status` field in db is `1`. When I click the login button, an "Account is inactive"  message appears on my auth page. Why am I getting this message?

My **ion_auth_model.php**:

```
   public function login($identity, $password, $remember=FALSE)
{
    $this->trigger_events('pre_login');

    if (empty($identity) || empty($password))
    {
        $this->set_error('login_unsuccessful');
        return FALSE;
    }

    $this->trigger_events('extra_where');

    $query = $this->db->select($this->identity_column . ', teacher_username, teacher_email, teacher_id, teacher_password, teacher_role, teacher_name, status, last_login')
                      ->where($this->identity_column, $this->db->escape_str($identity))
                      ->limit(1)
                      ->get($this->tables['users']);

    if($this->is_time_locked_out($identity))
    {
        //Hash something anyway, just to take up time
        $this->hash_password($password);

        $this->trigger_events('post_login_unsuccessful');
        $this->set_error('login_timeout');

        return FALSE;
    }

    if ($query->num_rows() === 1)
    {
        $user = $query->row();

        $password = $this->hash_password_db($user->teacher_id, $password);

        if ($password === TRUE)
        {
            if ($user->status == 0)
            {
                $this->trigger_events('post_login_unsuccessful');
                $this->set_error('login_unsuccessful_not_active');

                return FALSE;
            }

            $this->set_session($user);

            $this->update_last_login($user->teacher_id);

            $this->clear_login_attempts($identity);

            if ($remember && $this->config->item('remember_users', 'ion_auth'))
            {
                $this->remember_user($user->teacher_id);
            }

            $this->trigger_events(array('post_login', 'post_login_successful'));
            $this->set_message('login_successful');

            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    //Hash something anyway, just to take up time
    $this->hash_password($password);

    $this->increase_login_attempts($identity);

    $this->trigger_events('post_login_unsuccessful');
    $this->set_error('login_unsuccessful');

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: What type does the column "status" have in your database?

Comment: is there any problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a value within the empty forgotten_password_code field?
When the field is not empty, the user could be inactive.